# Relevance of In App Purchase feature for enterprise license

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-4.2

My company has an enterprise license for distributing iOS apps within the company itself. However in the provisioning portal, in App IDs section I can see "In App Purchase" option enabled or disabled for the different app ids.

What I want to know is that is there any relevance of In app purchase for enterprise applications, because whatever I know about it is that, it connects to the app store for functioning.

Comment: Were you able to implement the in-app purchase in to the enterprise App?

Comment: Sorry for replying late. I actually didn't try doing it. With an enterprise license, you are not allowed to publish to the app store, so I don't think you'd be able to use the in-app purchase feature.

Comment: Thanks Vin for the answer. It is good, if you can answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are not allowed to publish apps on the app store with a enterprise license, there doesn't seem to be any relevance of in-app purchase feature in this domain.